Let f monotone function in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $x_n$ Cauchy implies $f(x_n)$ Cauchy sequence
I have to prove is true the following, given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, f monotone in $\mathbb{R}$:
$\forall x_n$ sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.
I know that if $f$ is uniformly continuous or continous the statement is true.

but if f is monotone it is not necessarily convergent

You need $f$ to be continous.

@SeverinSchraven so only monotony is not sufficient? Can you give me a counterexample?

The statement as you wrote it was not a well formed formula.

@axi, what did you try in order to solve your problem?

Does this answer your question? How to show Cauchy continuity implies continuity A corollary of it is that if your $f$ is discontinuous, it won't satisfy your claim.

The statement is false. Let $f$ be given by $f(x)=x$ for $x\lt 0$, and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x\geq 0$. This is (strictly) monotone.
Let $x_n$ be the sequence given by
$$x_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-\frac{1}{n}&\text{if }n\text{ is even,}\\
0&\text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{array}\right.$$
This is Cauchy. But $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence, since it has a subsequence converging to $0$ amd a subsequence converging to $1$.

Please, do not answer very low-quality questions anymore

@Angelo I do not find this "very low quality". The "anymore" is also particularly insulting, as if you were chiding a continually misbehaving child. So kindly choose your phrasing more judiciously in the future. To be clear, there is no equivalence between "not low quality" and "explicitly describing the failed efforts in answering the question."

If $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then we have that $f$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequence iff $f$ is continuous. Note that monotonicity is never mentioned (or needed).
If $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, then it is bounded. If $f$ is continuous, then it is uniformly continuous on $[\,\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_n, \sup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}x_n\,]$ and hence $(f(x_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy too.
If $f$ is not continuous, then there exists $y_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = y_0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \neq f(y_0)$.
Now consider the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ where $z_{2k}=y_0$ and $z_{2k+1}=x_k$. We have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} z_n=y_0$ and hence this is a Cauchy sequence. However, we have
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f(z_{2k}) = f(y_0) \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f(z_{2k+1}). $$
Thus, $(f(z_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

Please, do not answer very low-quality questions anymore

@Angelo By all due respect, I am going to answer questions I find interesting. You are entitled to answer questions due to whatever criterion you like, but I do not particularly appreciate you telling me what I should be doing.
